# Classpath when jar library is in project jar

Tags: java, classpath

I have log4j jars packed in my main `prj.jar`. `prj.jar` content:

[image]

I run java program by using command in script:

```
java -cp ".:/opt/myprj/prj.jar" com.aaa.webSrv.meRun
```

Looks like program not finds `log4j` jars:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
```

Why and how to fix it?

UPD
My jar's created by Eclipse manifest looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ log4j-api-2.6.1.jar log4j-core-2.6.1.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: com.aaa.webSrv.meRun
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Is it enough to tell system regarding `log4j` jars?

Comment: You have to specify the log4j jars in the classpath too.

Comment: The log4j .jar files need to be outside prj.jar, not inside it.

Comment: But jar file contains manifest that describes log4j jar's  location. I have updated question body with manifest.

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps the problem is an old version of the `Jar-In-Jar Loader` that is not compatible with new versions of Java, which has disabled access to private methods via reflection. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68726179/5210701. Maybe it can help in your case.