# NoClassDefFoundError when using jar-in-jar loader

Tags: java, ant, executable-jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have an Eclipse project that I export to a runnable jar using an Ant build, and I use a jar-in-jar loader to put some jar libraries in the project jar. This used to work, and as I recall, updating to Java 9 is what broke it. I could be wrong, but I was just using my jar for a while until it stopped working.

Running the project in Eclipse works just fine, but when I use the jar and call a method from one of the libraries, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Doesn't matter which library.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myutils/MyUtils
        at packagename.Utils.input(Utils.java:42)
        at packagename.Main.main(Main.java:83)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myutils.MyUtils
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 7 more
```

Here's the Ant build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project ProjectName with Jar-in-Jar Loader">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR file Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required-->
    <!--define folder properties-->
    <property name="dir.buildfile" value="."/>
    <property name="dir.workspace" value="${dir.buildfile}/.."/>
    <property name="dir.libraries" value="${dir.buildfile}/../../libraries"/>
    <property name="dir.projectjars" value="${dir.buildfile}/../../project-jars"/>
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="${dir.projectjars}/jarname.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="packagename.Main"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ guava-19.0.jar jsoup-1.9.1.jar myutils.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <zipfileset src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/>
            <fileset dir="${dir.buildfile}/bin"/>
            <zipfileset dir="${dir.libraries}" includes="guava-19.0.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="${dir.libraries}" includes="jsoup-1.9.1.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="${dir.projectjars}" includes="myutils.jar"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

EDIT: Here's the `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.10.5
Created-By: 12.0.2+10 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Main-Class: packagename.Main
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ guava-19.0.jar jsoup-1.9.1.jar myutils.jar
Class-Path: .
```

Comment: You can investigate this further by opening your generated jar file using for example WinRar (or any other zip program that supports .jar files) and checking whether libraries actually end up in that jar or not. Finding the jars would reduce the problem to a class loading problem, not finding the jars would reduce the problem to an ant build problem (shading dependencies in the built jar).

Comment: @Pieter12345 The jars are indeed there.

Comment: In that case, the jar-in-jar-loader does not properly load the jars. The main class which you are calling runs this code to get references to the jars: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/jar%20in%20jar%20loader/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.java#L45-L57
You can see that it pulls the jar names from the manifest. Perhaps you have to include these jar names in the manifest? You'd have to refer to the documentation of the jar-in-jar-loader to get the exact format.

Comment: @Pieter12345 Well, I've added the manifest to OP. Even if I knew how to change the manifest to make it work, I don't know how I'd change the Ant build to create the proper manifest.

Comment: I ran into this problem today when I tried to use an old build.xml from a project I did a few years ago (Java 8).  It just wouldn't work (but used to work fine).  I ended up fixing it by regenerating the build.xml from within Eclipse (by checking the "Save as ANT script" checkbox in the "Export runnable jar" wizard).   You can compare the old and new to see the differences (which must be important because the new one worked fine).  Maybe this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Probably your file `jar-in-jar-loader.zip` is outdated and not appropriate for Java >= 9, I had the same issue.

**Solution**

To get the newest version of that file, right-click on your project -> Export -> Runnable JAR file -> Check "Save as ANT script" -> Finish. This will create the newest version of `jar-in-jar-loader.zip` in your project directory. The ant-script itself doesn't need to be adjusted, at least in my case.